# Can't start hostAPD. Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: networking, wifi, static-ip, access-point, hostapd

### Problem

I am using raspberry 3B. I want to make it as a wireless router. I added **TP-Link TL-WN725N** as an extra wireless device which uses **wlan1** as interface name. The device works flawlessly as a client.

Then, I have followed [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) tutorial.
up until this part:

```bsh
sudo systemctl unmask hostapd
sudo systemctl enable hostapd
sudo systemctl start hostapd
```

but, it returns :

```
Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So, I tried `systemctl status hostapd.service` , it returns:

```
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-04-22 22:35:39 BST; 1s ago
  Process: 2804 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

then `journalctl -xe`:

```
Apr 22 22:36:40 raspi-test systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
```

### current configuration

my **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ssid=raspitest
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

my **/etc/dhcpcd.conf**:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.16/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112

interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

what should I do?

**ps:**
*I always stuck with hostapd, 2 years ago, I posted [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/1018) to raspberry github. they respond very slowly, after therir fix on the documentation, now this problem emerges.*

Comment: Try running hostapd manually from the command line: `sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. You could also try with the `-d` or `-dd` options to print more debug messages. Right now, it's hard to tell what the problem is because running with `systemctl` doesn't let you see the logs very easily. If you run the command manually, you might be able to see some error messages that would be helpful.

Comment: Please edit your question provide complete output of `systemctl status hostapd.service` and `journalctl -xe --unit=hostapd.service`.

Comment: sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf will work without any problems

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Couldn't figure it out so I just added

```
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf&
```

to my rc.local file above "exit 0". Not exactly to code, but my Raspberry pi now works as an access point.